# can't add an image from API in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, png

I am trying to add an image from the website flagpedia

### how the json is formatted

```json
<img
  src="https://flagcdn.com/120x90/za.png"
  srcset="https://flagcdn.com/240x180/za.png 2x"
  width="120"
  height="90"
  alt="South Africa">
```

### my code

```dart
  Future<void> loadImage(String countryName) async {
    try {
      Response response =
          await get(Uri.parse('https://flagcdn.com/120x90/$countryName.png'));
      Map map = jsonDecode(response.body);
      name = map['alt'];  //String
      image = map['src']; //String
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('could not get $countryName');
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

### error

```
FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token PNG
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuoi are trying to parse the response as JSON. Use the `Image.network` widget instead.

Example

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flag Example')),
        body: Center(child: FlagImage(countryCode: 'za')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlagImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String countryCode;

  FlagImage({required this.countryCode});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.network(
      'https://flagcdn.com/120x90/$countryCode.png',
      width: 120,
      height: 90,
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
        print('Failed to load flag image: $error');
        return Text('Error loading image');
      },
    );
  }}
```